# I can not remove the border-bottom that appears on the bootstrap mobile navigation when active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navigation

I created this home page on the bootstrap framework and used the built in navigation class for responsive & mobile devices. There was a black border that appeared when you select the 3 lines (either by shrinking the browser or do an inspect element and select a mobile device) that I was able to add a border:none and border:transparent and turn to white, but I can not get rid of the border completely. Can someone please help me figure out what I need to do to fix this? URL is http://mistryweddings.com/Schmooz3.0/schmooz.html

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work.

```
.navbar-toggle{border:0 !important}.
```